# reload a div/table and the function associated with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this code that does not run properly or my was incorrect. I have a table that has rows with huge texts and are linked to a modal, after closing the modal it reloads the table. Then it should call the function that shortens the text. The calling of the function does not work.

This is the script from 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/

```
$('#edit-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#table').load(document.URL +  ' #table');
    hidesome(); //this does not work or is ther 
})
function hidesome() {
            var showChar = 100;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "more";
    var lesstext = "less";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
        if(content.length > showChar) {
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
            $(this).html(html);
        }
    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    hidesome();
});
```

Where is the conflict? How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the call to `hidesome` to `load` callback, otherwise it fires before you get response from server:

```
$('#edit-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#table').load(document.URL +  ' #table', function() {
        hidesome();
   });    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callback, or order the results appear to be different

```js
$('#edit-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
$('#table').load(document.URL +  ' #table', function() {
    hidesome();
   });    
})
function hidesome() {
            var showChar = 100;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "more";
    var lesstext = "less";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
        if(content.length > showChar) {
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
            $(this).html(html);
        }
    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    hidesome();
});
```

```html
<button id='#edit-modal'>test</button>
```